# Unity SteamVR Actions not Working in Build

Tags: unity-game-engine, steamvr

I am trying to switch to another scene when the headset is removed. It is already working in the Unity editor, however, not in the build.

Setup:

- Unity 2018.3.6f1
- SteamVR Unity Plugin v.2.2.0
- Vive Pro

This code is working in the editor:

```
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using Valve.VR;
public class EndGame : MonoBehaviour
{    
    [Tooltip("This action lets you know when the player has placed the headset on their head")]
    public SteamVR_Action_Boolean headsetOnHead = SteamVR_Input.GetBooleanAction("HeadsetOnHead");

void Update()
{
    if (SteamVR.initializedState != SteamVR.InitializedStates.InitializeSuccess)
    {
        return;
    }

    if (headsetOnHead != null)
    {
        if (headsetOnHead.GetStateDown(SteamVR_Input_Sources.Head))
        {
            StopCoroutine(RestartGame());
        }
        else if (headsetOnHead.GetStateUp(SteamVR_Input_Sources.Head))
        {
            StartCoroutine(RestartGame());
        }
    }
}
IEnumerator RestartGame()
{
    yield return new WaitForSecondsRealtime(3);
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Startscene", LoadSceneMode.Single);
    yield return null;
}
}
```

In the Editor \actions\default\in\HeadsetOnHead is referenced to public SteamVR_Action_Boolean headsetOnHead.

The actions.json (including /actions/default/in/HeadsetOnHead) is in the build folder and the logs don't show any errors.

Comment: Try using a different version of unity

Comment: I tried the code in a clean project with Unity version 2018.2.0f2 and it indeed worked. I still try to figure out if the Unity version is the problem or if there are any other issues in my project.

Comment: One thing that can help you to indentify the issue is to install SRdebugger. That asset allow you to catch error in your build. you have to click 3 times on a corner of your build screen to open a "console" you can now check console messages exactly like in Unity Editor. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to SteamVR_LoadLevel instead of scene management solved the issue for the current Unity Version.

Also, the script was attached to the SteamVR Player Prefab in the scene. Now it's placed on a seperate gameobject in the scene, to avoid issues with dont distroy on load with the Player prefab.